# Does SCID have a way of showing the top 2 engine moves?

Tags: scid

At the moment, the Analysis window shows over 32 variations in a random order of strength.

Is it possible to just show the top 2 strongest moves?

If I right click in the window all the moves disappear and I get some text saying "Click here to see moves".

If I click on the "Click here..." text nothing happens.

If I right click again, I get 1 variation.

If I hover over the `1` drop down at the bottom I get a tooltip which is displayed off screen so cannot be read.

Eventually more variations appear but they all seem to be based around the strongest move.

Comment: the 32 variations actually are just the lines that the engine evaluated in order to find the strongest move, it's not a ranking of all moves. By default, it only gives the strongest move, shown in the header above in bold ( where it says something like +0.8 Depth: 30 Nodes: 754343k (1102kn/s) Time: 93.72s).

Answer (score 1):

In your analysis window, you will see a toolbar up top that looks something like the following. If you change the number (the 1 at the right-hand side of the picture), you will be able to vary the number of top variations you see.

[image]